# Why am I seeing 'connection reset by peer' error?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, system

I am testing [cogen](http://code.google.com/p/cogen/) on a Mac OS X 10.5 box using python 2.6.1.  I have a simple echo server and client-pumper that creates 10,000 client connections as a test.  1000, 5000, etc. all work splendidly.  However at around 10,000 connections, the server starts dropping random clients - the clients see 'connection reset by peer'.

Is there some basic-networking background knowledge I'm missing here?

Note that my system is configured to handle open files (launchctl limit, sysctl (maxfiles, etc.), and ulimit -n are all valid; been there, done that). Also, I've verified that cogen is picking to use kqueue under the covers.

If I add a slight delay to the client-connect() calls everything works great.  Thus, my question is, why would a server under stress drop other clients when there's a high frequency of connections in a short period of time?  Anyone else ever run into this?

For completeness' sake, here's my code.

Here is the server:

```
# echoserver.py

from cogen.core import sockets, schedulers, proactors
from cogen.core.coroutines import coroutine
import sys, socket

port = 1200

@coroutine
def server():
    srv = sockets.Socket()
    srv.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    addr = ('0.0.0.0', port)
    srv.bind(addr)
    srv.listen(64)
    print "Listening on", addr
    while 1:
        conn, addr = yield srv.accept()
        m.add(handler, args=(conn, addr))

client_count = 0

@coroutine
def handler(sock, addr):
    global client_count
    client_count += 1
    print "SERVER: [connect] clients=%d" % client_count
    fh = sock.makefile()
    yield fh.write("WELCOME TO (modified) ECHO SERVER !\r\n")
    yield fh.flush()
    try:
        while 1:
            line = yield fh.readline(1024)
            #print `line`
            if line.strip() == 'exit':
                yield fh.write("GOOD BYE")
                yield fh.close()
                raise sockets.ConnectionClosed('goodbye')
            yield fh.write(line)
            yield fh.flush()
    except sockets.ConnectionClosed:
        pass
    fh.close()
    sock.close()
    client_count -= 1
    print "SERVER: [disconnect] clients=%d" % client_count

m = schedulers.Scheduler()
m.add(server)
m.run()
```

And here is the client:

```
# echoc.py

import sys, os, traceback, socket, time
from cogen.common import *
from cogen.core import sockets

port, conn_count = 1200, 10000
clients = 0

@coroutine
def client(num):
    sock = sockets.Socket()
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    reader = None
    try:
        try:
            # remove this sleep and we start to see 
            # 'connection reset by peer' errors
            time.sleep(0.001)
            yield sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", port))
        except Exception:
            print 'Error in client # ', num
            traceback.print_exc()
            return
        global clients
        clients += 1
        print "CLIENT #=%d [connect] clients=%d" % (num,clients)
        reader = sock.makefile('r')
        while 1:
            line = yield reader.readline(1024)
    except sockets.ConnectionClosed:
        pass
    except:
        print "CLIENT #=%d got some other error" % num
    finally:
        if reader: reader.close()
        sock.close()
        clients -= 1
        print "CLIENT #=%d [disconnect] clients=%d" % (num,clients)

m = Scheduler()
for i in range(0, conn_count):
    m.add(client, args=(i,))
m.run()
```

Thanks for any information!

Comment: on server side, srv.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1) gets me to 16K client connections...

it dawned on me that at this point I'm running out of ephemeral ports:

> net.inet.ip.portrange.hifirst: 49152
> net.inet.ip.portrange.hilast: 65535

Comment: I suppose then, all is well really.  I'm all ears if someone can
explain to me why *not* using TCP_NODELAY causes connections to be
dropped.

Comment: Re: ephemeral ports... I was able to bring up a second IP and manually bind the client sockets to each port in [1024,65535] on each IP. I was able to connect over 80K clients from the same machine running the server. Whee!

Answer (score 8):

Python's socket I/O sometimes suffers from connection reset by peer.   It has to do with the Global Interpreter Lock and how threads are scheduled.  I [blogged](http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/iblog/architecture/C551260341/E20081031204203/index.html) some references on the subject.

The `time.sleep(0.0001)` appears to be the recommended solution because it adjusts thread scheduling and allows the socket I/O to finish.

Comment: So what happens when I have clients in the wild that can connect at any time?  Granted, I'm not *expecting* 1000 connection attempts per second but there's no way I'm going into production without understanding this 100%.  I suppose I could rate limit connections with iptables.

Comment: "at around 10,000 connections, the server starts dropping random clients" More than that, I doubt your server can actually do much with 10,000 concurrent connections.  Can you really open and serve 10,000 files?  Can you really do 10,000 DB queries?

Comment: @2pence: since your question disclosed nothing, I was forced to assume.  Since I was forced to assume, there was no possible way for me to assume correctly.  Please update your question with new facts.

Comment: @2pence: Sorry.  Your first comment indicated that you had additional questions, but it was missing some facts.  That's why I chimed in.  I apologize for trying to understand your comment.  If it was meant to be opaque, I missed the point.

Comment: Dead link. Can you elaborate on the solution?

Comment: http://www.itmaybeahack.com/homepage/iblog/architecture/C551260341/E20081031204203/index.html