# Python SSL example from docs gives "Connection reset by peer" error

Tags: python, ssl

I'm trying to run the example code provided in the documentation for the `ssl` module here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#client-side-operation

The server-side code is similar to the example given in the documentation, and it throws this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serve.py", line 16, in <module>
    ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 381, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

And the client-side code, also similar to the example in the documentation, throws this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 8, in <module>
    ssl_sock.connect((host, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 331, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 324, in _real_connect
    raise e
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

As far as I can see, I've copied the examples provided in the documentation quite closely, so I don't know what the problem is. All of my TCP, UDP and ICMP ports are open, so I don't think it is a firewall issue.

<sub>(I've edited this question to cut out my code for brevity, as it really is quite similar to the example provided in the link. If you want to see my code, look at the history of this question.)</sub>

Comment: what if you use it without specifying the cert files?

Comment: @User: it will throw an exception, stating that when `server_side` is true, they must be specified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem. I generated the private key and the certificate using command like this:

```
$ openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem
Generating a 1024 bit RSA private key
# ...
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:US
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:MyState
Locality Name (eg, city) []:Some City
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:My Organization, Inc.
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:My Group
Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []:myserver.mygroup.myorganization.com
Email Address []:ops@myserver.mygroup.myorganization.com
$
```

**The crucial part is that the "common name" entered must match the domain name of the server.** I thought that when `cacerts` is `ssl.CERT_NONE`, which it is by default for `wrap_socket`, this wouldn't be checked, but I was wrong. It's always checked. One night's sleep and it's the first thing I thought of to verify!

Hopefully this will be useful to someone else who gets this cryptic error message.

If this doesn't solve it, you might be suffering from **deep packet inspection**. I got this error again when I was on a university network, but not on any other network, and I'm fairly certain it was because of deep packet inspection.