# Python openSLL Server Crash on connection - odd error on SSL

Tags: python, ssl, python-2.7, openssl

I am trying to get a SSL server running, so it can accept JSON object and reply with other JSON objects. However, before doing JSON objects, I decided to do a simplified version and I came across this weird error with SSL that I cannot find anything about. Solutions on the generation of the certificate did not seem to work, unless I am doing something wrong. So here is everything I did:

Python Server

```
import socket
import re
import ssl

# Standard socket stuff:
host = ''  # do we need socket.gethostname() ?
port = 8080
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(1)  # don't queue up any requests

# Loop forever, listening for requests:
while True:
    csock, caddr = sock.accept()
    connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(csock,
                                 server_side=True,
                                 certfile="cert.pem",
                                 keyfile="cert.pem",
                                 ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
    print "Connection from: " + `caddr`

    dataBuf = connstream.recv(4096) # read what is there to read
    extraData = connstream.recv(4096) #see if there is more
    while len(extraData) != 0: #if something extra was read
        dataBuf += extraData
        extraData = connstream.recv(4096) #check again



    print '--------'
    print len(dataBuf), dataBuf
    # Look in the first line of the request for a move command
    # A move command should be e.g. 'http://server/move?a=90'
    match = re.match('GET /move\?a=(\d+)\sHTTP/1', dataBuf)
    if match:
        angle = match.group(1)
        print "ANGLE: " + angle + "\n"
        connstream.sendall("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"+
                             "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"+
                             "Connection: close\r\n"+
                             "\r\n"+
        """<!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
        <title>Success</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        Boo!
        </body>
        </html>\r\n
        """)
    else:
        # If there was no recognised command then return a 404 (page not found)
        print "Returning 404"
        connstream.sendall("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n")
    #connstream.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    connstream.close()
```

Generation of key and certificate : I am not sure if I am doing something wrong in the "Common Name" part, as I am giving localhost.localdomain following the post [Python SSL example from docs gives "Connection reset by peer" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954467/python-ssl-example-from-docs-gives-connection-reset-by-peer-error)

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout cert.pem
```

How I am completing the fields:

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:UK
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:C
Locality Name (eg, city) []:C
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:U of C
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:CL
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:localhost.localdomain
Email Address []:unis
```

`Errors: after going to https://localhost:8080/move?a=77 on a browser (Firefox and Chrome)`

```
Connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 39107)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ser.py", line 29, in <module>
    dataBuf = connstream.recv(44096) # read what is there to read
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 241, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 160, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1359: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
```

Help appreciated! Thanks!

ps: I tried TLSv1 and PROTOCOL_SSLv23, same error...

///FOLLOW UP:

I went onto Firefox and manually added the certificate.

Now I get:

```
Connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 39220)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ser.py", line 29, in <module>
    dataBuf = connstream.recv(44096) # read what is there to read
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 241, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 160, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1359: error:14094419:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert access denied
```

Any Ideas?

//Another try:

I told Firefox to trust the certificate and now I get

```
Connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 39248)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ser.py", line 29, in <module>
    dataBuf = connstream.recv(44096) # read what is there to read
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 241, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 160, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1359: error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate
```

Searches for this give nothing!

//Follow up:

Regenerated keys and cert using http://devsec.org/info/ssl-cert.html, also put as the Common Name `localhost`. I get connection, but it server gets stuck and never replies... Could there be some problem in the read part?

Comment: If you're generating a self-signed certificate, then the "Common Name" (CN) must precisely match the hostname in the HTTP `Host:` header, i.e. the hostname you're using in the URL, so if you're using the URL `https://localhost:8080/move?a=77`, then the CN needs to be `localhost` not `localhost.localdomain`.

Comment: @Aya OK, I changed that, I also ensured that Firefox was not deleting the certificate after checking. I get connection, but the GET request never finishes. Any idea why? It just sits there and never finishes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the followup question, I suspect the problem is with this code...

```
dataBuf = connstream.recv(4096) # read what is there to read
extraData = connstream.recv(4096) #see if there is more
while len(extraData) != 0: #if something extra was read
    dataBuf += extraData
    extraData = connstream.recv(4096) #check again
```

...which will attempt to read from the socket until it hits EOF.

However, most browsers will use a [persistent HTTP connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) by default, which means they won't close the outbound half of their socket after sending the request, so the EOF won't occur, and your code will be blocking on one of those `recv()` calls.

If you want to implement a conformant HTTP server, you'll need to familiarize yourself with [the protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616). You'll have to read the HTTP headers line-by-line, paying attention to the `Connection`, and `Content-Length` headers, and once you hit the end of headers, you should only attempt to read up to `Content-Length` bytes if the request headers contained `Connection: keep-alive`.

The protocol can get a little more complicated, so it might be simpler just to use the built-in Python HTTP server, and wrap the socket. A quick Google for `python https server` yields a [fairly simple example](http://www.piware.de/2011/01/creating-an-https-server-in-python/) as the first result.

Comment: Hello Aya. It's definitely along the lines of that. I don't need any sort of conformance, I just need to get a message from an extension, process it and reply with a JSON string containing some serialised images and meta-data. So my question is. Is it overkill to use the already baseHTTP servers for what I need? Or would you say that it is justified and will actually be faster? I just don't want to waste time reading on the library and changing the actual server... Thanks!

Comment: @unixsnob Well, if you need to handle requests generated by Firefox, you'll need a reasonably conformant server, and it's a lot simpler to use the existing `BaseHTTP` server than writing your own. If you're just using HTTP for some custom client-server code, then you could use something simpler than HTTP instead - it depends on the use-case.